# Error starting admin for DemoSite for Broadleafcommerce

Tags: java, spring, maven, broadleaf-commerce

I installed the latest version (broadleaf-5.2.2.1-GA) of Broadleaf Commerce demo site following the setup instructions. Then I ran command - `mvn spring-boot:run -X` for admin and following error was displayed:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project boot-community-demo-admin: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run for parameter agent: Cannot assign configuration entry 'agent' with value '/Users/anikanchan/DemoSite-broadleaf-5.2.2.1-GA/admin/target/agents/spring-instrument.jar' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.io.File[] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project boot-community-demo-admin: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run for parameter agent: Cannot assign configuration entry 'agent' with value '/Users/anikanchan/DemoSite-broadleaf-5.2.2.1-GA/admin/target/agents/spring-instrument.jar' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.io.File[]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run for parameter agent: Cannot assign configuration entry 'agent' with value '/Users/anikanchan/DemoSite-broadleaf-5.2.2.1-GA/admin/target/agents/spring-instrument.jar' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.io.File[]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException: Cannot assign configuration entry 'agent' with value '/Users/anikanchan/DemoSite-broadleaf-5.2.2.1-GA/admin/target/agents/spring-instrument.jar' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.io.File[]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.AbstractConfigurationConverter.failIfNotTypeCompatible(AbstractConfigurationConverter.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ArrayConverter.fromConfiguration(ArrayConverter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.convertProperty(CompositeBeanHelper.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.setProperty(CompositeBeanHelper.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:32)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:575)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
```

How do I solve this? Please help.

Comment: Try running `mvn install` first before executing your spring boot launch command.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Maven 3.2, update to the latest version of Maven, minimum version of 3.3.9.

Comment: I have same issue with maven 3.0.9, after I increase to 3.5.4 It work success.

Answer (score -1):

You can Run through the Eclipse IDE it wont shows any errors and run successfully
for running local it will show some errors. you can run in eclipse see the documentation to run broad-leaf on eclipse
link: [documentation to run broad-leaf on eclipse](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started/ide-setup/eclipse-setup)